# Difference between making the changes in Object Explorer directly in SQL Server Management Studio versus making the changes in local file

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, ssms

What is the difference when we make changes in a file in SQL Server Management Studio directly using Object Explorer and when we make changes in a file by opening the file, i.e. Using Ctrl+O?

Comment: Those operations arent comparable. One is altering an object in the database, the other a file on the file system.

Comment: So, when we will make a change in the stored procedure of SQL Server Management Studio, where the change will be affected?

Comment: In the database...

Comment: Yes, but in the development? In the git repository?

Comment: No, in the database. The *actual* database... The database you are connected to. the database hosted on the instance (you are also connected to). The **Database**. Databases aren't stored in a git repository... I have no idea what you mean by the database in development; development isn't a location it's part of the developement cycle; often followed by something like UAT before going to production.